# Name-error when formatting NTFS on OS X 10.8.4 using "diskutil" (Terminal)

Tags: macos, ntfs, core-storage, fusion-drive

I have a 2011 Macbook Pro 13 inch - OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion), which i upgraded with a SSD. I installed the original HDD as second drive instead of the optical.
I need to change the filesystem for volume (disk1s4) from HFS+ to NTFS.
Paragon NTFS 10.0.2  driver is installed and activated.
I just keep getting an error saying that the name is not a valid volume name for that file system.
BTW: I also tried with Tuxera NTFS before installing Paragon.

Here is the Terminal log:

```
******-Mac:~ ******$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 59F163EA-4746-4D9D-B625-B6F5211CE7D1
    =========================================================
    Name:         FUSIONDRIVE
    Status:       Online
    Size:         457289637888 B (457.3 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume C6F57ECC-A2F1-4D49-90D5-0F42AD176F15
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     83289645056 B (83.3 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 89F3AF10-FBCD-4E87-88B2-D202D79C54DF
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     373999992832 B (374.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 456C6A33-EB2B-468E-9987-4678B4AEC72A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume C608A444-A777-462C-8935-E4613B5CBE05
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:               disk2
            Status:             Online
            Size (Total):       454804242432 B (454.8 GB)
            Size (Converted):   -none-
            Revertible:         No
            LV Name:            CSVolume
            Volume Name:        CSVolume
            Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
******-Mac:~ ******$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         374.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data bootcamp                125.2 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         83.3 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Win7 boot               44.3 GB    disk1s4
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS CSVolume               *454.8 GB   disk2
******s-Mac:~ ******$ diskutil eraseVolume UFSD_NTFS "windows" disk1s4
windows does not appear to be a valid volume name for its file system
******-Mac:~ ******$ diskutil eraseVolume NTFS "windows" disk1s4
Formatting is not supported by: NTFS ntfs Windows NT File System (NTFS) 
******-Mac:~ ******$
```

EDIT:

Just to be clear. This is the volume i would like to format:

```
4:                  Apple_HFS Win7 boot               44.3 GB    disk1s4
```

EDIT 2:

I think I found a workaround-solution by searching google. In a [thread](http://www.tonymacx86.com/mountain-lion-desktop-support/94024-how-can-i-get-windows-partition-fusion-drive.html) (answer #3) in the tonymacx86 forum I found this line `diskutil eraseVolume fat32 WINROOT /Volumes/WINROOT`. I changed it to `diskutil eraseVolume fat32 WIN7 disk1s4`. It is now formatted as FAT32, which i think can be changed using the Windows 7 install disk.

Now it looks like this:

```
******s-Mac:~ ******$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         374.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data bootcamp                125.2 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         83.3 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data WIN7                    44.3 GB    disk1s4
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS CSVolume               *454.8 GB   disk2
******s-Mac:~ ******$
```

Comment: Consider picking a horse in terms of asking if anyone knows a package that works or pick one config (OSX + paragon + tuxera) and don't let us guess if one or both is actually installed.

Comment: Sorry, but i thought it was clear, when i wrote "BTW: I also tried with Tuxera NTFS before installing Paragon." - I have only one NTFS driver installed at the time ;)

Comment: The confusion was all on my side, but I worried another might be confused. It's a very good question, I'll promote it on chat in case someone has an idea better than mine (which is good on how things work - but lame on options for you to fix things at present.).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using stock OS X since even on a normal drive (and not getting into any core storage considerations), diskutil does not support the UFSD_NTFS and NTFS formats:

```
Mac:~ bmike$ diskutil listFilesystems
Formattable file systems

These file system personalities can be used for erasing and partitioning.
When specifying a personality as a parameter to a verb, case is not considered.
Certain common aliases (also case-insensitive) are listed below as well.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PERSONALITY                     USER VISIBLE NAME                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExFAT                           ExFAT                                           
Free Space                      Free Space                                      
  (or) free
MS-DOS                          MS-DOS (FAT)                                    
MS-DOS FAT12                    MS-DOS (FAT12)                                  
MS-DOS FAT16                    MS-DOS (FAT16)                                  
MS-DOS FAT32                    MS-DOS (FAT32)                                  
  (or) fat32
HFS+                            Mac OS Extended                                 
Case-sensitive HFS+             Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)                
  (or) hfsx
Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+   Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)     
  (or) jhfsx
Journaled HFS+                  Mac OS Extended (Journaled)                     
  (or) jhfs+
```

You would need to use a tool other than `diskutil` to perform the formatting, but the Apple tools will respect and leave alone these volumes or make space for them by leaving free space or a FAT/ExFAT partition that you could then erase and leave NTFS data on the drive. Additionally, the Paragon pre-sales FAQ for 10.0.2 doesn't mention either Fustion Drive or Core Storage, so I would assume they don't support this. Have you asked them if core storage is supported?

Comment: Thanks, but according to this manual http://www.tuxera.com/mac/mac_manual.pdf it should be possible. See 3.2.1 in the manual. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you verify that the tools work on a smaller non CS drive? If that works, you'd have a great support case and question here. I missed your setup with Paragon, so perhaps they interact poorly with tuxera? The document you link has no date and talks about 10.4 so perhaps it's not ready for core storage yet?

Comment: I actually didn't test it. Just assumed it worked. Now I see that the bootcamp volume is not recognized in Paragon settings, and i'm not able to copy files to the bootcamp partition.

Comment: Bootcamp plops a FAT partition on the HDD only - it's not actually using the cs volume and SSD - so it shrinks things so that the fusion drive uses all the SSD and a portion of the HDD if you carve out space for Bootcamp. You might need to boot to the recovery HD and run `diskutil list` or Disk Utility to see those details.

Comment: I think I found a workaround-solution by searching google. In a thread in the tonymacx86 forum I found this line `diskutil eraseVolume fat32 WINROOT /Volumes/WINROOT`. I changed it to `diskutil eraseVolume fat32 WIN7 disk1s4`. It is now formatted as FAT32, which i Think can be changed using the windows 7 install disk.

Comment: Please edit that in or make your own answer. That's how bootcamp always works. Make a FAT volume and let another tool do the formatting. I assumed you had some other "need for formatting NTFS" than simply getting a Windows install going.

Comment: Nope. I just need to install windows, but it still bugs me that i couldn't get the NTFS formatting to work.